# Simple Regex Matching in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I know there are a few questions and answers on StackOverflow about using regex in jQuery, but they seem a bit complicated.

I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
$("div").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().className.replace(/photo-\w*/, 'photo-2');
});
```

It seems like a simple operation: replace the parent of the clicked div (which could have a class something like 'photo-5'), with the 'photo-2'

Can someone explain why the above code doesn't work, and provide the simplest / cleanest method possible do this? Thanks

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(this).parent() will give you a jQuery object. Try this

```
$("div").click(function () {
    $(this).parent()[0].className = $(this).parent()[0].className.replace(/photo-\w*/, 'photo-2');
});
```

Comment: Just for the record, jQuery has its own `.get` function which can be used instead of `[]`. It also supports negative indices etc.

Comment: Am I batty, or would the result of the replace need to be assigned somewhere? (i.e. `className = className.replace(...)`)

Comment: Brad's answer was great too, but I think Shankar's solution was slightly cleaner, thanks v much guys.

Answer (score 1):

Replace needs to be assigned somewhere, not just executed (otherwise it has not effect on the actual value). That said, try this:

```
$('div').click(function(){
    var $p = $(this).parent().get(0);
    $p.className = $p.className.replace(/photo-\w*/, 'photo-2');
});
```

[Working on my end](http://jsfiddle.net/DAug9/).